# How to write a chrome extension that displays the countdown from a webpage in a pop-up?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I've never posted on here before so I apologize if I'm doing something wrong.
I wanted to know if anyone had any tips on how I should go about creating this chrome extension.

There's an online game I play that has a page where users can collect items when it's "open". When it's closed, there's text on the page that tells you how many minutes are left until it opens again.

I'd like to write an extension that "looks" at the page and basically copies over that text to display so that you can see how many minutes are left without having to visit the page itself. What's the simplest way to do that? I'd like it to be quick enough to eventually work as a kind of alarm when the timer reaches 1 minute so that users know to go to the page & get there right when it opens.

When looking this question up I only really find information about web scrapers which doesn't seem like what I'm looking for. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty cool thing to do! I did it a while back for the MU Away game (don't know if it still exists).

I did it using Python actually, everytime I had an event on their website, it'd send me an email with what I wanted (i.e. Reset time was 0 so I could reset my character and start griding again)

You could use Python 3.8, selenium webdriver and SMTP Lib.

Let me know if you need more specific information.

web scrapers would be the easiest and fastest way of doing it.
1-2h in python or a week with chrome extension, but that might be me though, I'm kinda new to chrome extensions